# entity framework, self-tracking entity and sqlserver file stream

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, self-tracking-entities

I just start a project where I need to have a WCF services that read and write files.

The architecture is based on DDD using Entity Framework Self-Tracking Entity.

The simple GUI should show a grid with a list of file and then click the row you can download it.

Can I use the file stream sql server 2008 feature with this architecture? Which strategy is the best one to manage this kind of entity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Filestream` will not help you when using EF. EF doesn't use streaming feature, it loads it as `varbinary(max)`. If you wan to take advantage of filestream you must [load it from database with ADO.NET directly](http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/03/16/saving-and-retrieving-file-using-filestream-sql-server-2008.aspx) and you need a [streaming service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) to pass it back to the client in efficient way.